# Calculate the set of unique abbreviations for a given set of strings

Tags: javascript

how can I do it in javascript? With ruby I used this library:

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/abbrev/rdoc/index.html

is there anything similar for javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I found it:

https://github.com/isaacs/abbrev-js